# How to use treeview with data grid view column in c# windows with editable cell

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am new to C# window applications. I want to use `TreeView` control inside `DataGridView Column` in C# windows forms. In this `DataGridView` cells are editable and can store data, I mean user can set and get data from it.

[image]

I want to create something like this.

Comment: This might provide you with a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912873/treeview-with-columns

Comment: tried this... https://sourceforge.net/projects/treeviewadv/?source=dlp ?

Comment: Read also [this article](http://10tec.com/articles/treeview-in-datagridview.aspx)

Comment: If you use a 3rd party grid like Infragistics or Telerik grid, these features are built in and really easy to use. The Treeview will render automatically based on any ICollection<> properties on your bound data object.

Comment: We use Devexpress tools and the grid control has this built in. Don't try to reinvent the wheel, for a few hundred dollars you can get this and much more functionality on your grids.