# Grouping DataGridView using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Can anyone explain to me how to make grouping for the DataGridView in C# because I have no idea about this topic?

I searched on the websites but I didn't understand anything.

Also I found somethings about  GridViewHelper but I didn't know how to deal with it because it gives me this error (The type or namespace name 'GridViewHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference

Note: I am using Windows Forms C#

[This is my datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjZpY.jpg)

[I want to make it  exactly like this one according to name column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjiH1.png)

Comment: Have a look at [TreeView with columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912873/treeview-with-columns)

Comment: DGVs do not support grouping out of the box. ListViews do.

Answer (score 0):

You need at first two different tables, using a common field to link them (like the Serial Number, for instance).

But the built-in DataGridView of VS does not support that kind of display. You will achieve it only with custom or third-party controls.

See here to more info:

http://10tec.com/articles/datagridview-grouping-two-recipes.aspx
http://www.infragistics.com/products/windows-forms/grid#Overview