# Control with treeView with Columns

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

Does any control support Treeview with columns and checkboxes in C#(Winforms)?

Can you please let me know which control do the above requirement.

Comment: see https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Get-Selected-Checked-CheckBoxes-of-TreeView-on-Button-click-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page! - Winfroms dos not have such a thing out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

ObjectListView will make you happy if you target for desktop app. See http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have seen, but there is a similar [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912873/treeview-with-columns) already.
I use [TreeView with Columns](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23746/TreeView-with-Columns) from Codeproject. It lacks checkbox support, however in comments someone wrote that has implemented it.

[image]